# Shopify Application Proxy Set Template

Tags: templates, shopify, liquid

Can you set which template to use when loading content via an application proxy in shopify?

I can set which layout file to use by using;

```
{% layout 'theme.app_proxy' %}
```

But trying to set the template has no effect;

```
{% assign template = 'app_proxy' %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know.

However you can return liquid as your app proxy response and Shopify will process it as though it was part of the theme.

If you are trying to override a standard template you'll have to write a file to the theme and update the things (e.g products/blogs/pages) to use the custom template.

Answer (score 0):

It is working in my tests. Perhaps it has been corrected since this question was asked.

Make sure you set the liquid header in your proxy response:

```
'Content-Type: application/liquid'
```

Then in your response body, you can assign a template name:

```
{% assign template = 'app_proxy' %}
```

And it will be used throughout your theme.  For example if your layout file uses the template name to output a class in the body:

```
<body class="{{ template }}">
```

This will now display:

```
<body class="app_proxy">
```